# TensorFlow runtime error -- UnimplementedError

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am new to tensor flow. I am following this tutorial https://learningtensorflow.com/lesson9/

My Python env is 3.5.2 with tensor flow 1.9.0 and numpy 1.15.0. I run python env in Anaconda3 on Windows 10 platform. The codes from the tutorial were ran in Jupyter notebook.

When running

```
with tf.Session() as session:
initial_board_values = session.run(initial_board)
X = session.run(board_update, feed_dict={board: initial_board_values})[0]`
```

I got the errors as follows:

---

```
UnimplementedError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1321     try:
-> 1322       return fn(*args)
   1323     except errors.OpError as e:

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1306       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(
-> 1307           options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1308 

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _call_tf_sessionrun(self, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1408           self._session, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1409           run_metadata)
   1410     else:

UnimplementedError: Unsupported numpy type 5
     [[Node: PyFunc_1 = PyFunc[Tin=[DT_INT32], Tout=[DT_INT32], token="pyfunc_1", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_board_1_0_0)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

UnimplementedError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-d85af0ec9968> in <module>()
      1 with tf.Session() as session:
      2     initial_board_values = session.run(initial_board)
----> 3     X = session.run(board_update, feed_dict={board: initial_board_values})[0]

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    898     try:
    899       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 900                          run_metadata_ptr)
    901       if run_metadata:
    902         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1133     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1134       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1135                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1136     else:
   1137       results = []

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1314     if handle is None:
   1315       return self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
-> 1316                            run_metadata)
   1317     else:
   1318       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, handle, feeds, fetches)

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1333         except KeyError:
   1334           pass
-> 1335       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1336 
   1337   def _extend_graph(self):

UnimplementedError: Unsupported numpy type 5
     [[Node: PyFunc_1 = PyFunc[Tin=[DT_INT32], Tout=[DT_INT32], token="pyfunc_1", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_board_1_0_0)]]

Caused by op 'PyFunc_1', defined at:
  File "C:\Users\Pillar\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\Pillar\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Pillar\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "C:\Users\Pillar\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "C:\Users\Pillar\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 477, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "C:\Users\Pillar\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "C:\Users\Pillar\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 888, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "C:\Users\Pillar\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Pillar\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "C:\Users\Pillar\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "C:\Users\Pillar\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Pillar\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Pillar\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "C:\Users\Pillar\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 235, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "C:\Users\Pillar\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "C:\Users\Pillar\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 196, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "C:\Users\Pillar\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 533, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Pillar\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2698, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "C:\Users\Pillar\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2802, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "C:\Users\Pillar\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2862, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-8-8d546cf3ed00>", line 2, in <module>
    board_update = tf.py_func(update_board, [board], [tf.int32])
  File "C:\Users\Pillar\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 384, in py_func
    func=func, inp=inp, Tout=Tout, stateful=stateful, eager=False, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\Pillar\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 227, in _internal_py_func
    input=inp, token=token, Tout=Tout, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\Pillar\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_script_ops.py", line 130, in py_func
    "PyFunc", input=input, token=token, Tout=Tout, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\Pillar\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\Pillar\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3414, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\Pillar\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1740, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

UnimplementedError (see above for traceback): Unsupported numpy type 5
     [[Node: PyFunc_1 = PyFunc[Tin=[DT_INT32], Tout=[DT_INT32], token="pyfunc_1", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_board_1_0_0)]]
```

Comment: Google collab can execute [this](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1G2Ns9D1843V61V6wpUaVaqU-RDLfen_H#scrollTo=VuT1nKZyDdf_) without error.